# How does the Form.getCommand(int index) work?

Tags: codenameone

I have a current `Form(previousForm)` with a `previousForm` as a parameter. My goal is to get a specific Command of this previousForm (reload the data of the previousForm and then do `showBack()`) from the current Form. The problem is that I can't reach this specific Command from my current form. While doing research on this problem, I found `getCommand(int index)` method, and I would like to clarify how it works.

The documentation of `Form` says that it

> Returns the command occupying the given index

How can I find the index of my Command? Or how can I set it?
I see there is a Command's constructor `Command(String command, int id)` , however this `id` is not the index.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going at this in a different route. Just do something like this:

```
public class MyForm extends Form {
    public void reload() {
       //...
    }
}
```

Then in your back command just downcast to `MyForm` and invoke reload. Make sure all forms are of type `MyForm`.

`getCommand()` is meant for use with `getCommandCount()` so you can loop over all commands and extract them from the parent `Form`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of extending. I'll definitely try it. So far I solved my problem by 
`Form f = new Form();
f.getToolbar().setBackCommand(previousForm.getBackCommand());`
And thank you for explanation of `getCommand()`. Now it's clear